# <Swing> Character rendering stops working after a while

Tags: java

I'm making a small program Matrix Animation and - Character rendering stops working after a while. I think that Random is too slow, because if you do the same thing, but not with Random and take characters in the "for" loop, everything works fine.

It's my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.SplittableRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestClass {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;

    private static volatile char charToDraw = '\u30A0';
    private static  char[] alphabet;
    private static SplittableRandom random = new SplittableRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initAlphabet();
        setCoordColumn();
        setPanel();
        setFrame();
        paintChar();
    }

    private static void initAlphabet() {
        alphabet = new char[96];
        int n = 0;
        for (char c = '\u30A0'; c <= '\u30FF'; c++) {
            alphabet[n] = c;
            n++;
        }
    }

    private static void setFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("Matrix Animation");
        frame.setSize(900, 900);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(panel);
    }

    private static void setPanel() {

        panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

                for (Columns column : Columns.values()) {
                    g.setFont(column.font);
                    g.drawString(String.valueOf(charToDraw), column.xCoords, 22);
                }
            }
        };
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    private static void paintChar() {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {

            charToDraw = alphabet[random.nextInt(97)];

            panel.repaint();

        }, 0, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private static void setCoordColumn() {
        int n = 0;
        for (Columns column : Columns.values()) {
            column.xCoords = n;
            column.font = new Font("ms mincho", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, random.nextInt(10) + 12);
            n += 30;
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;

public enum Columns {
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    Column4,
    Column5,
    Column6,
    Column7,
    Column8,
    Column9,
    Column10,
    Column11,
    Column12,
    Column13,
    Column14,
    Column15,
    Column16,
    Column17,
    Column18,
    Column19,
    Column20,
    Column21,
    Column22,
    Column23,
    Column24,
    Column25,
    Column26,
    Column27,
    Column28,
    Column29,
    Column30;


    public int xCoords;
    public Font font;
}
```

I don't know how to optimize it.
Also, a loop in drawing a symbol is probably not the optimal solution. But so far, Graphics g is coping.

Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your alphabet array only has a length of 96 (which means that valid indizes are from 0 to 95 inclusive):

```
alphabet = new char[96];
```

but in your `paintChar()` method you treat is as containing 97 elements:

```
charToDraw = alphabet[random.nextInt(97)];
```

This code will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  as soon as the random generator returns 96.

The scheduled thread is automatically terminated when an exception occurs.

To fix this replace the line above with

```
charToDraw = alphabet[random.nextInt(alphabet.length)];
```